# Managing actors system creation code

Tags: scala, akka

This question is about how to create actors and compose/maintain actors creation logic.

Akka provides logic isolation with actors and message, but how should I create an actors systems?

In very simple example project it is ok to create actors manually in some kind of `App` object with `system.actorOf` method. It works fine for 5-10 actors, but how should I work with hundreds of different actors?

For example, I have 50 different dao like actors. Even if I put all of them under "dao" root actor I still should create 50 actors by myself.

Is it any way to push this login in some kind of config file or so?

Should I really write and maintain this creation and wire all actors together manually?

Comment: Do these dao actors have different logic (i.e. you have 50 different domain entities), or are they used, for example, for load balancing? If first, then you have to make them manually; if second, you have to configure [routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/routing.html). You can, however, define some of actor's configuration in `application.conf` file (like actor's dispatcher).

Comment: If creating actors manually is tedious for you, then you can write such config library by yourself, I do not see any difficulties with it. It could even work with the same `application.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks for comment. These actors hold different logic

Comment: Then you have to do it with `Props` and `ActorSystem`. Why do you think it is bad? Akka, after all, is a library for actors concurrency, not for dependency injection. To resolve dependencies between actors you can use any DI framework, e.g. Guice, or even that is embedded in Scala - Cake pattern. BTW, *hundreds* of *different* actors seems to be an overkill. Are you sure you cannot refactor your program to reduce this number? Or at least split your program into independent parts which have lesser number of actors?

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your comments! I am wonder how will I maintain actor system creation code. I can imagine how can I unit test it and it is not possible to have compile time errors if someone do it wrong. Just thought that some kind of best practice may exist.